# Как передать значение из Callback функции после загрузки изображения?

Tags: javascript

Хочу передать значения высоты и ширины загружаемого изображения. До этого пытался делать это с помощью return, но выяснил, что это не работает и неправильно. После решил делать с помощью callback функции.
Но появился вопрос - как передать значения высоты и ширины?

Как я пытлася получить значения с помощью return без callback:

```
popup: {
    dimentions: {},
    testFunc: function testFunc(url) {
         this.dimentions = this.getMeta(url);
         console.log(this.dimentions); //browser returns {} h: 1920 w: 720
         console.log(this.dimentions.w); //browser returns undefined

    },

    getMeta: function getMeta(url){
         var meta = {};
         var img = new Image();
         img.onload = function(){
              meta.w = this.width;
              meta.h = this.height;
         };
         img.src = url;
         return meta; //browser returns {} h: 1920 w: 720
    },
}
```

Как я хочу сделать это с помощью callback, но не знаю как получить значения:

```
testFunc: function testFunc(url) {
     this.getMeta(url, function() {
          this.dimensions = .... //how can i find dimensions from a callback function?
     });
     console.log("console log: " + this.dimentions);    
},

getMeta: function getMeta(url, cb){
     var meta = {};
     var img = new Image();
     img.onload = cb;
     img.src = url;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dimensions: {},
getMeta: function getMeta(url){
     var meta = this.dimensions;
     var img = new Image();
     img.onload = function(){
          meta.w = this.width;
          meta.h = this.height;
     };
     img.src = url;
},
```

```js
var img = new Image();
document.body.appendChild(img);
img.onload = function() {
  console.log("In onload: " + img.width + " x " + img.height);
}
img.src = "https://assets.pernod-ricard.com/uk/media_images/test.jpg";
console.log("Immediately (picture hasn't arrived yet): " + img.width + " x " + img.height);
```

Comment: Всё равно undefined

Comment: Что "undefined"?

Answer (score 0):

Решил так:

```
resizePopup: function resizePopup(url) {

            this.getMeta(url, function(){
                ratio = gallery.popup.dimentions.w / gallery.popup.dimentions.h;
                if(ratio <= 1) {
                //console.log("console.log: " + popupWidth);
                content_height = $(".popup-item").height();
                content_width = content_height*ratio;
                    $(".popup-item").width(content_width + "px");
                } else {

                }
            });
        },

        getMeta: function getMeta(url, cb){
            //var meta = {};
            //meta = this.dimentions;
            var img = new Image();
            img.onload = function() {
                gallery.popup.dimentions.w = this.width;
                gallery.popup.dimentions.h = this.height;
                cb();                    
            }
            img.src = url;
        },
    },
```